# Further constraining a generic function from a Swift Protocol

Tags: swift, generics

I have a Swift protocol defined like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func genericMethod<T:MyProtocol>(param:T) -> ()
}
```

I can implement the generic method in a base class like this:

```
class MyBaseClass : MyProtocol {
    func genericMethod<T where T:MyProtocol>(param:T) -> () {
        println("Performing generic method for type \(T.self)")
    }
}

class MySubClass : MyBaseClass {
    ...
}
```

So far, so good. I can implement this method and it compiles and runs just fine.

Now, I want to do something similar but in my base class I want to further constrain the type of the generic method by requiring it to conform with a protocol such as `Comparable`. I try this:

```
class MyBaseClass : MyProtocol {
    func genericMethod<T where T:MyProtocol, T:Comparable>(param:T) -> () {
        println("Performing generic method for type \(T.self)")
    }
}
```

Once I add this additional constraint on type `T`, the class `MyClass` will not compile because it does not conform to the protocol anymore.

It seems like adding an additional constraint on a generic type should not cause it to cease conforming with a protocol. What am I missing? It seems to me that the protocol is saying that `genericMethod` must be passed a parameter of a type that conforms with `MyProtocol`. When I go to implement this in `MyBaseClass` - just one possible implementation of `MyProtocol` - that I should be able to restrict that implementation further by saying that the parameter myst conform with `Comparable` *in addition to* `MyProtocol`

Is there a way to refine a generic type in a base implementation like I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I don't understand why you're surprised. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but it seems to me that the protocol says, "Whoever adopts me must implement `genericMethod` with the parameter being his own type. But `T:MyBaseClass, T:Comparable` is _not_ MyBaseClass's own type, since MyBaseClass does not adopt Comparable. So, as the compiler says, you've violated the contract laid out by the protocol.

Comment: Using the `Self` reference in the protocol was just one way to demonstrate the problem. I get the same problem if I use one protocol and then another. I will update the question to make it more clear why I am surprised at this behavior

Comment: OK, thanks for the revision. Well, the answer to the question of why the compiler doesn't like it is that these are not a match. The protocol requirement `func genericMethod<T:MyProtocol>(param:T) -> ()` is not _the same as_ `func genericMethod<T where T:MyProtocol, T:Comparable>(param:T) -> ()`. You are saying in a kind of mental justificatory footnote "one is a more restricted version of the other", but that doesn't matter to the compiler; the point is that one is _not_ the other.

Comment: To see this, try a simpler variant: `func genericMethod<T> (param:T) -> ()` and `func genericMethod<T where T:Comparable>(param:T) -> ()`. They are not a match either, and it's clearer why, I think. To put it another way, you seem to think that one generic is a kind of "subclass" or "subset" of the other. But that's not how these generic signatures work. It's a match or it isn't.

Comment: I suggest you review the Liskov Substitution Principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: *"`MyClass` will not compile"* -> did you mean `MyBaseClass` or `MySubClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the additional constraint on a generic type *should* cause it to cease conforming with the protocol because the protocol is supposed to guarantee conformance, and conformance cannot be guaranteed with subtypes that aren't `Comparable`. If you want all `MyProtocol` objects to conform to `Comparable` then you should make it part of the `MyProtocol` definition.

```
protocol MyProtocol: Comparable {
    //...
}
```

I haven't tried this, but it might also work if you make `MyBaseClass` a `Comparable` type.

Comment: I don't want all `MyProtocol` objects to conform to Comparable. I want all subclasses of `MyBaseClass` to inherit a `genericFunction` method that is implemented with the knowledge that those specific subclasses also happen to conform with `Comparable`. I will have other `MyProtocol` base classes that implement the protocol differently, without necessarily depending on an assumption that their subclasses conform with `Comparable`

Comment: Then you need to specify that MyBaseClass conforms to Comparable. Does the code compile if you do that?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to go the other way - define your protocol's version of the generic as the most *restrictive* case. This compiles:

```
protocol P {
    func genericMethod<T where T:P, T:Comparable>(param:T) -> ()
}

class C1 : P {
    func genericMethod<T> (param:T) -> () {} // compiles even though omits Comparable
    func test() {
        genericMethod(C1()) // compiles even though C1 is not a Comparable
    }
}
```

Comment: Feels like a complier bug.